# Sublevels in the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If you create sublevels, i.e. if there are 3 tasks in the 1st level? is it better to fit them into one scene or each task into another scene? just a thought. how to save it in the game later?

Comment: The scene in unity is a file that saves your object's data on the disk. When you unload a scene, unity unloads the previous scene from memory. So, it depends on your game. If you have large scenes or limited memory, it's better to separate your game into different scenes otherwise, there is no significant difference.